# Missing HTML Tags getElementsByTagName - DOMDocument

Tags: php, html, domdocument

I'm trying to get the `span` with class `product-rating-count-container__count` from a url.

When I examine the that url with google developer tools, I can see those `span` tags exists.

But when I list them using `DOMDocument`, `loadHTMLFile` as below, they are missing.

```
<?php

$url = 'https://www.trendyol.com/magaza/profil/trendyol-m-968';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTMLFile($url);

$links = $doc->getElementsByTagName('span');

foreach ($links as $link) {
  $classy = $link->getAttribute("class");
  echo   $classy."<br>";
}
?>
```

How can I get those `span` tags I want ?

Comment: Go to that URL, and then check the HTML source code, instead of the DOM view. If the elements you are looking for are not in there - then they most likely have been added dynamically via JavaScript.

Comment: (And in that case - https://www.google.com/search?q=scrape+javascript+generated+content+site%3Astackoverflow.com)

Comment: @CBroe, I understand that they are added afterwards. Is there an easy trick to get them?

Comment: You'll basically need something, that can actually execute the JS and provide a DOM for it to operate on. Not exactly a new topic, see previous comment.